# Helper class for easily positioning objects in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I think it is quite OK already, but from a design-pattern perspective, it would be interesting to hear if I have done it right.  I'm also interested to know whether the implementation is OK from a best-practice C++ point of view.

I made a helper class in order to easily position objects in cocos2d-x. The client can use the class like this:

```
restartButton->setPosition(
                           Positioner()
                           .withSize(restartButton->getContentSize())
                           .withAlignment(HorizontalAlign::LEFT)
                           .withAlignment(VerticalAlign::TOP)
                           .withMargin(Position::LEFT, 1)
                           .withContainer(ccp(0.0,0.0), contentSize)
                           .build()
                           );
```

Here is the helper class:

```
class VerticalAlign
{     
public:
    enum ALIGNMENT
    {
        TOP,
        CENTER,
        BOTTOM
    };
};


class HorizontalAlign
{        
public:
    enum ALIGNMENT
    {
        LEFT,
        CENTER,
        RIGHT
    };

    static HorizontalAlign::ALIGNMENT 
    from(VerticalAlign::ALIGNMENT alignment)
    {
        switch (alignment)
        {
            case VerticalAlign::TOP:
                return HorizontalAlign::RIGHT;
                break;
            case VerticalAlign::BOTTOM:
                return HorizontalAlign::LEFT;
                break;
            case VerticalAlign::CENTER:
                return HorizontalAlign::CENTER;
                break;
            default:
                std::cerr << "unexpected/unsupported alignment!\n";
                throw new std::exception();
        }
    }

};


class Position
{
public:
    enum POSITION
    {
        LEFT,
        TOP,
        RIGHT,
        BOTTOM,
        NR_POSITIONS
    };
};



// origo for positions are at center,center (i.e. pos = 5,5 and size = 10,10 gives a top,left,right,bottom=5,5,15,15)
class Positioner
{
public:


    Positioner()
    :
    mHorizontalAlignemnt(HorizontalAlign::CENTER),
    mVerticalAlignemnt(VerticalAlign::CENTER),
    mContainerSize(cocos2d::CCSize(0.0,0.0)),
    mContainerOrigo(ccp(0.0, 0.0))
    {
        mMargins.resize(Position::NR_POSITIONS);
    }

    virtual
    ~Positioner()
    {
    }

    Positioner &
    withContainer(cocos2d::CCPoint containerOrigo, cocos2d::CCSize containerSize)
    {
        mContainerSize = containerSize;
        mContainerOrigo = containerOrigo;
        return *this;
    }

    Positioner &
    withSize(cocos2d::CCSize size)
    {
        mSize = size;
        return *this;
    }

    Positioner &
    withAlignment(HorizontalAlign::ALIGNMENT align)
    {
        mHorizontalAlignemnt = align;
        return *this;
    }

    Positioner &
    withAlignment(VerticalAlign::ALIGNMENT align)
    {
        mVerticalAlignemnt = align;
        return *this;
    }

    Positioner &
    withMargin(Position::POSITION marginAt, double margin)
    {
        mMargins[marginAt] = margin;
        return *this;
    }

    // returns origo of a rectangle with given size and vertically and horizontally aligned within a given container such that it meets the given margins
    // however, alignment takes precedence over margins (i.e. if centered then will be positioned centered even if it does not meet the margins given)
    CCPoint build()
    {
        return ccp(xOrigo(), yOrigo());
    }

private:

    double xOrigo(HorizontalAlign::ALIGNMENT align, double marginLeft, double marginRight, double size, double containerOrigo, double containerSize)
    {
        switch (align)
        {
            case HorizontalAlign::LEFT:
                return containerOrigo + size / 2.0 + marginLeft;
                break;
            case HorizontalAlign::RIGHT:
                return containerOrigo - size / 2.0 - marginRight + containerSize;
                break;
            case HorizontalAlign::CENTER:
                return containerOrigo + containerSize / 2.0;
                break;
            default:
                std::cerr << "unexpected/unsupported alignment!\n";
                throw new std::exception();
        }
    }

    double xOrigo()
    {
        return xOrigo(mHorizontalAlignemnt, mMargins[Position::LEFT], mMargins[Position::RIGHT], mSize.width, mContainerOrigo.x, mContainerSize.width);
    }

    double yOrigo()
    {
        return xOrigo(HorizontalAlign::from(mVerticalAlignemnt), mMargins[Position::TOP], mMargins[Position::BOTTOM], mSize.height, mContainerOrigo.y, mContainerSize.height);
    }

    HorizontalAlign::ALIGNMENT mHorizontalAlignemnt;
    VerticalAlign::ALIGNMENT mVerticalAlignemnt;
    cocos2d::CCSize mContainerSize;
    cocos2d::CCPoint mContainerOrigo;
    cocos2d::CCSize mSize;
    std::vector<double> mMargins;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me offer a different point of view.

Using a builder, in itself, is fine.

Loki’s alternative works nicely but if you’ve got more complex objects it doesn’t scale any more. A builder can then be used as an alternative to keep the actual object (not the builder, the built object) immutable.

To make it clear: *in this case* I’d probably go with Loki’s approach – and I’d use this approach as much as possible but sometimes a builder yields clearer code.

But when you use a builder, make sure that you don’t fall into the trap of constructing an unfinished object: that is, the `build` method should make sure that the constructed object is *valid* and *complete*, and should raise an exception if that’s not the case. That way, you’ve made sure *via the type system* that the resulting object will be in a valid state.

Furthermore, having a `build` method is Java cruft. In C++, you can just define an implicit conversion to the type you want to build. Although there are normally good reasons *against* implicit conversions, they don’t apply in this particular case – the conversion is safe (if you make it safe, see above) and should never lead to confusion.

With that, I’d replace `build` by the following:

```
operator CCPoint() const
{
    verify_object_is_valid();
    return ccp(xOrigo(), yOrigo());
}
```

And the usage is shortened a bit:

```
restartButton->setPosition(
    Positioner().withSize(restartButton->getContentSize())
                .withAlignment(HorizontalAlign::LEFT)
                .withAlignment(VerticalAlign::TOP)
                .withMargin(Position::LEFT, 1)
                .withContainer(ccp(0.0,0.0), contentSize));
```

(Reformatting also helps.)

But note that this is still longer, and not actually clearer, than Loki’s alternative code without a builder.

Comment: Great suggestion with the implicit conversion. "but sometimes a builder yields clearer code." what's your rule-of-thumb/criteria for ctors vs builders? I tend to go for builders if > 4-5 parameters and/or I want to delegate partially built objects and/or the construction is heavy in logic (separate construction from app-logic). I tend to use ctors for objects with 1-3 config-params. While constructors gives combinatorial explosions and/or a myriad of either unnamed alternative constructors or a pool of silly classes PositionerHorizontalAlignCenterVerticalAlignCenterWithNoMargins(container).

Comment: @j-a I have no real rule of thumb, the choice comes up too rarely. I’ve used a builder previously when I wanted the actual object to be immutable and the construction was performed in multiple steps (notably for a complex graph structure) or modifying the actual object was expensive (think `String` vs. `StringBuilder`).

Comment: @j-a I think Loki just used `Positioner` and `CCPoint` interchangeably in his code example. In practice, the code could have been made to work via an implicit conversion as well. I’ll complement my answer when I find time, at the moment I’m unfortunately *very* busy because of looming deadlines, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a cross between an actual answer, and a really extended comment to @LokiAstari's.

As far as the "fluent interface" (I *really* hate that phrase) goes, I think you need to look at two things: the average case and the worst case. I'd agree with @Loki's statement that in the worst case, the "fluent" interface is truly horrible. The code ends up so long it borders on ridiculous.

That leaves only the average case as its hope for redemption. *If* a default-constructed `Positioner` object has most of the right setting most of the time, so you *usually* only need:

```
Positioner().withSize(restartButton->getContentSize()).build())
```

Then it *might* be acceptable.

I'd note, however, that this still doesn't seem to provide any real advantage over @Loki's approach of using `Location`, `Margins` and `Container`. If the default values for margins (for example) are adequate, you can provide default values in the ctor for `Margin` just as easily as in the default constructor for `Positioner`. If the `Positioner` shown above is usually adequate, then his can also use defaults for the other arguments, so it'll end up as:

```
Positioner(restartButton->getContentSize())
```

I see at least one other substantial advantage for representing the `Location`, `Margins` and `Container` as classes of their own: even when the default values aren't adequate, you're likely to use the *same* margins (for example) in quite a few different places. By creating and naming a set of margins, you gain readability *and* centralize information about a set of margins in one place so they're easy to change consistently. Just for example, you might easily have one set of margins in one form, and a different set of margins in a different form.

```
Location TL(HorizontalAlign::Left, VerticalAlign::TOP);

Margins order_entry(0, 1, 0, 0);
Margins week_totals(1, 2, 1, 1);

Positioner(order_button.getContentSize(), TL, order_entry);

Positioner(totals_button.getContentSize(), TL, week_totals);
```

To summarize, it appears to me that the "fluent interface" (did I mention how much I **hate** that phrase?) will nearly *always* result in code that's longer and harder to read or understand than simply providing arguments to the constructor, in this case in the form of other objects representing the parts of an entire "position".